# Output capacitor current of boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I am simulating a boost converter. The input voltage is 8 V and the duty ratio is 0.3. The load resistor is 1 ohm. I want to plot the output capacitor current. In DTs time when MOSFET is on, the capacitor current should be negative of load current. But in the simulation it is not coming like this. The simulation is ideal. What is the problem? Please help.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your schematic? And what are the current waveforms you're getting?

Comment: please provide the schematics and the waveform you're getting out of the simulation so we can help you

Comment: does your topology use two FETs or one FET and one diode?

Comment: The conventional boost converter I am simulating. It has 1 MOSFET and one diode.

Comment: @joribama...The simulation is done in Matlab. The screenshot of the result is added.

Comment: The load resistor is 1 Ohm and output voltage is 11.3~11.6V so output current should be 11.3~11.6A. Capacitor current appears to be about the same. What is the problem?

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Everything looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're not plotting the capacitor *output* current, but you're plotting just the capacitor current. It is the capacitor's charge current (when the gate signal is low) and the decharge current (when the gate pulse is high).

When the capacitor is decharging this current is about -11.4A and equals the load current (in magnitude). The capacitor is decharging so the current is negative.
Exactly as shown in the simulation plot.